# MultiSelectList data binding and Model validation in MVC

Tags: c#, razor, data-binding, multi-select, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my code to display List of Names in MultiSelectList

**Controller**

```
// GET
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var bookViewModel = new BookViewModel
    {
        AuthorList = _Authors.GetAuthors()
                          .Select(a => new SelectListItem { 
                                     Value = a.Id.ToString(), 
                                     Text = a.Name }
                                 ).ToList()
    };

    return View(bookViewModel);
}

// POST
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BookViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Some code
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AuthorIds, Model.AuthorList, new { multiple = "multiple" })
    <input id="btnCreate" type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

This code works fine when if Model validetes, but if `ModelState.IsValid = false`, when it returns the model back to the view (`.. else { return View(model); }`), model does not contain the `AuthorList` and shows an error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'AuthorIds'.

in the view line `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AuthorIds, Model.AuthorList....`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize authorlist again in your else part

```
else
    {
model.AuthorList = _Authors.GetAuthors()
                          .Select(a => new SelectListItem { 
                                     Value = a.Id.ToString(), 
                                     Text = a.Name }
                                 ).ToList()
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is there a way to preserve the previous Author List rather than fetching it again from the database?

Comment: If your if is working properly u must have assigned value to AuthorList. so have variable outside if else and then u can use same variable

Comment: @Nalaka526 remember the web is stateless. The Get and Post requests could come 20 minutes apart. That said if the authors list is used in a lot of places you could cache it rather than going to the DB.